# Delay invoking method in WCF web service - the first time

Tags: wcf, networking, delay, basichttpbinding

I have a WCF Web Service Framework 4 that exposes a very simple method for authentication in **BasicHttpBinding**

Nothing special:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAutorizedUser
{
   [OperationContract
   GetAuthentication bool (string UserName, string Password
}
```

The problem is that when I call that method from a remote pc, before the response I have a delay of 20 seconds, the first time. The cause is not the code inside the method: even if I comment completely that code, I have the same delay. From the second time then, the method is invoked normally and quickly.

Other html pages hosted in that server are quick.

If the call of the method starts from the server hosting the web service, there's no problem. With other remote pcs in our office lan, the problem always occurs, with the only exception of another server, where the delay is limited to 5 seconds.

I realize that the terms of the problem are very generics, but instinctively I think that the issue may reside in some WCF settings. What do you think? Could you help me?

Thank you in advance,
Pileggi

Comment: Try to host simple HTML page in your server. It is network issue if that page is slow as well when you open it from remote host. Add network tags and description for your environment to question in that case.

Comment: @Dmitry Harnitski thanks for your response. A simple html page hosted in our server is quick... I don't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is useDefaultWebProxy in the client web.config, I had to set it to false:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="pippo" ... useDefaultWebProxy="false">
        ...
```

Now my problems are here:

[Visual Studio "Add Service Reference" - not gets all service settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246892/visual-studio-add-service-reference-not-gets-all-service-settings)

and here:

[Set useDefaultWebProxy=false on WCF Client with the Web-References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247129/set-usedefaultwebproxy-false-on-wcf-client-with-the-web-references)

Pileggi

Comment: We had a problem with ~20s delay on the call between two services - it was very hard to find its reason as it did occur only for some AppPool credentials. Thanks to your answer we traced the problem to those users' different proxy settings.